# Bringing the activity to foreground

Tags: android, service, android-activity, foreground

In my activity class i call start service and service works fine.In the service on the basis of some test i want to bring the activity in the foreground(the activity that start the service).What to write in the service class to get the activity in foreground.I need it foreground because if user opens another application then my activity goes to background.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use this when you start you activity
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

Comment: My activity starts a service.Service is running.its ok.But when user opens another application the activity that started service is gone to the background.From my service i want to do something so that i can get my app on foreground

Comment: you can do this in your service  Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);

Comment: Actually i tried this code earlier.But can't run because of this keyword in setClass method.But when you put it i tried again and with getApplicationContext() instead of this i get it done.Thanks

Comment: @Rasel I have the same problem as you, I put  Intent start = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
      start.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
      startActivity(start); but if user had open another application, my application is not bring to foreground. How did it work at you?